# Can't make partition, GParted shows 450 GB unused

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, disk

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I can't create new partition on sda 2, GParted shows 450 GB unused but still I can't do partition. Please let me know what's the problem?

[image]

Comment: You will need to shrink a partition first. Currently, the whole disk is used by (nearly empty) partitions. Shrinking a partition (resizing) will make room for a new one.

Comment: Little key icons say partitions are mounted. You cannot change mounted partitions. Generally best to use gparted from Ubuntu live installer or use a gparted live flash drive, so all partitions are unmount. Live installer may mount swap, so umount it with swap-off if necessary.

Comment: `sda` can have partitions added, since it's the whole drive. `sda2` (with a number at the end) ***is*** a partition. It can't have partitions added to it. You have to make `sda2` smaller and then use the empty space left over to add a new partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sda2 is already a partition which is being used as  your main file system formatted as ext4. **IT IS NOT UNALLOCATED SPACE**
Gparted is only telling you that it has 450GB unused.

However if you want to add a new partition , you would have to shrink your current sda2 partition and then create a new partition in the new **UNALLOCATED SPACE**

https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVHXdH7Wo3s